# What's the name of this kind of graph?

Tags: r, data-visualization

I would like to create this type of visualization. It comes from a paper about political self-placement in the left-right continuum: Attitudes, Ideological Associations and the Left-Right Divide in Latin America (Weisehomeier, Doyle, 2012).

[image]

Does anybody know what these graphs are called and how to create them in R?

Comment: A dotplot, or [dotchart](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/dotchart.html).

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: It might be an effect plot, hard to tell from that specific example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a relief of my reply-as-a-comment, here's a more qualified answer. This kind of graphical output is usually called a dot plot or a dot chart, after Cleveland.<sup>1</sup> One dimensional scatter plots are also called dotplots in some statistical packages. As @mdewey  mentioned, this can also be used to show the mean effect of a variable (with its standard error or confidence intervals) on a given outcome, but in this case each "point" are a different kind of aggregated statistic (i.e., the average of numerical values, rather than a frequency of count data).

It is a nice alternative to more classical bar charts, because of its inherent low [data-ink ratio](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/131400/930), valued by Edward Tufte.<sup>2</sup> Moreover, this kind of graphical representation fits nicely into the design of trellis displays, by Becker and coll.,<sup>3</sup> which among other things allow for facetting (i.e., conditioning in statistical language) and more (e.g., "shingle") --- Ross Ihaka has a nice presentation on this aspect in his [Topic in Computational Data Analysis and Graphics](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/%7Eihaka/787/) course.

You will probably find many such illustrations on this site, but the main R packages that are generally used are the builtin `dotchart` function, its [lattice](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lattice/index.html) counterpart, `dotplot`, or the [ggplot2](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/) package, where `geom_point` can safely replace `geom_bar` or `geom_hbar` (note that `geom_dotplot` is the equivalent of R's builtin `stripchart`, for one dimensional scatter plots). The [UC Business Analytics R Programming Guide](https://uc-r.github.io/cleveland-dot-plots) provides some nice illustrations using the latter approach as well.

**References**

<sup>1</sup> Cleveland, W.S. and McGill, R. (1984).  Graphical Perception: Theory, Experimentation, and Application to the Development of Graphical Methods. *Journal of the American Statistical Association*, 79(387), 531–554.

<sup>2</sup> Tufte, E. (2001). *The Visual Display of Quantitative Information*, (2nd ed.). Graphics Press.

<sup>3</sup> Becker, R.A., Cleveland, W.S and Shyu, M.-J. (1996). The Visual Design and Control of Trellis Display. *Journal of Computational and Graphical Statistics*, 5(2), 123–155.